# how can i use default props in react.js or react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

For example. i have Feeds and Upload Components. also i have ImageFeedList component in Feeds, Upload Components

(Feed.js)

```
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {StackNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {RandomUserDataContext} from '~/Context/RandomUserData';
import ImageFeedList from '~/Components/ImageFeedList';

type NavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<FeedsTabParamList, 'Feeds'>;
interface Props {
 navigation: NavigationProp;
 }


   const Feeds = ({navigation}: Props) => {

   const {getMyFeed} = useContext(RandomUserDataContext);

   const [feedList, setFeedList] = useState<Array<IFeed>>([]);

   const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFeedList(getMyFeed(24));
  }, []);


  return (

     <ImageFeedList
      feedList={feedList}
      loading={loading}
      onRefresh={() => {
      setLoading(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
      setFeedList(getMyFeed(24));
      setLoading(false);
      }, 2000);
      }}
     onEndReached={() => {
     setFeedList([...feedList, ...getMyFeed(24)]);
      }}
     onPress={() => {
     navigation.navigate('FeedListOnly');
     }}
      />
     );
      };

   export default Feeds;
```

(Upload.js)

```
 import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
 import {RandomUserDataContext} from '~/Context/RandomUserData';
 import ImageFeedList from '~/Components/ImageFeedList';

  const Upload = () => {
  const {getMyFeed} = useContext(RandomUserDataContext);
  const [feedList, setFeedList] = useState<Array<IFeed>>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
  setFeedList(getMyFeed(24));
  }, []);

     return (

   <ImageFeedList
    feedList={feedList}
    loading={loading}
    onRefresh={() => {
    setLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
    setFeedList(getMyFeed(24));
    setLoading(false);
    }, 2000);
  }}
  onEndReached={() => {
    setFeedList([...feedList, ...getMyFeed(24)]);
  }}
  />
 );
 };

 export default Upload;
```

(ImageFeedList.js)

```
import React from 'react';

import {
FlatList,
Image,
Dimensions,
NativeSyntheticEvent,
NativeScrollEvent,
} from 'react-native';

  import styled from 'styled-components/native';

  interface Props {

 id?: number;
 bounces?: boolean;
 scrollEnabled?: boolean;
 feedList: Array<IFeed>;
 loading?: boolean;
 onRefresh?: () => void;
onEndReached?: () => void;
  onScroll?: (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => void;
 onPress?: () => void;

}

const ImageFeedList = ({
 id,
 bounces = true,
 scrollEnabled = true,
feedList,
loading,
onRefresh,
onEndReached,
onScroll,
onPress,
}: Props) => {
const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const imageWidth = width / 3;

return (

<FlatList
  data={feedList}
  style={{width}}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
    return `image-feed-${id}-${index}`;
  }}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
  bounces={bounces}
  numColumns={3}
  onRefresh={onRefresh}
  onEndReached={onEndReached}
  onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
  refreshing={loading}
  onScroll={onScroll}
  scrollEventThrottle={400}
  renderItem={({item, index}) => (
    <ImageContainer
      style={{
        paddingLeft: index % 3 === 0 ? 0 : 1,
        paddingRight: index % 3 === 2 ? 0 : 1,
      }}
      onPress={onPress}>
      <Image
        source={{uri: item.images[0]}}
        style={{width: imageWidth, height: imageWidth}}
      />
    </ImageContainer>
  )}
/>
    );
    };

   export default ImageFeedList;
```

what i want to ask is that in Feeds Component i have OnPress and i can pass onPress to ImageFeedList component as Props but there is no onPress props in Upload Component. however error is not gonna happen eventhough there is no onPress in Upload because i have a

```
interface Props {
onPress?: () => void;
 }
```

this code i define onPress Props in In ImageFeedList components it meanse if i don't get Props onPress then it's fine

i can use this default props in typeScript

but my question is that how can i use default props in react and react-native other than typeScript??

is there way??

Comment: Please re-formulate your question into compartmentalized sentences. Unable to understand what it is you're asking currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using default props in ImageFeedList.

```
const ImageFeedList = ({
     id,
     bounces = true, /* <<< has a default value "true"*/
     scrollEnabled = true, /* <<< has a default value "true"*/
     ...
     onPress /* <<< has no defaut value*/,
    }: Props) => {...}
```

you could add something like that as a default for onPress

```
const ImageFeedList = ({
     ...
     onPress = () => console.log(), /* a default prop as an arrow function */
    }: Props) => {...
```

Here is another example of how to pass a function as a default parameter

```js
function y(prop = function () {console.log("I log default")}){
  prop(); 
};
y(); // will log "I log default"
y(function () {console.log("I am not a default");}); // will log "I am not a default"
```

Update:
You could also check if onPress is defined, before using it.

```
    <ImageContainer
  ...
  onPress={() => typeof onPress === "function" && onPress()}>
```

Comment: oh thank you but how can i use this code in just react?? onPress?: () => void;

Comment: @jackvolten what do you mean by just react? React is JavaScript, and React functions are simple JS functions. So the syntax is the same for React and JS.

Comment: i maen in typescript i can use  interface Props and i can define onPress is unnecessary 
just like thie ....
 interface Props {
 onPress?: () => void;
}

but if i don't use typescript how can i define onPress is not necessary??

Comment: If you don't use TypeScript, you don't have to define onPress as an unnecessary parameter. Simply don't pass it, or ignore it in your code. This won't cause any errors.

Comment: but how about this ? Feed.js and Upload.js both of these components use ImageFeedList component .. but only Feed component need onPress that's why feed components pass Onpress to ImageFeedList as props  

 and imageFeedLise use 

interface Props {
 onPress?: () => void
}



but if i don't use typescript there is no way to use unnecessary props?

Comment: I have updated my answer, but am still not sure, if that is what you want

Comment: oh that coule be work!! thank you so much henk!!!!!

Comment: if that answered your question, please mark it as an answer to close this issue. Also, a thumbs up is always appreciated ;)

Comment: henk i want to mark your answer but i can't find mark button and thumb up button ...
how can i do that? this is my first question in stackoverflow......

Comment: You can find the arrow up, arrow down, and a checkmark to accept the answer on the left top of the answer.